# How would you create grooves in wood objects like this?

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling a lot of wooden things at the moment and want to try and achieve the effect below. What methods would you use to create small notches and long grooves like this?

[image]

Comment: don't you want to fake it with Bump or Normal maps?

Comment: @moonboots Not in this case no. It's use isn't just for within Blender.

Comment: what are the orange lines for? Have you tried to highlight some parts or are your talking about the classic grooves on the wood planks?

Comment: The orange is because those are selected objects.

Comment: @moonboots The orange is just selection inside Unity. You can ignore that. My question specifically is about the classic grooves as you describe which are part of the mesh of each plank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something as simple as that?

[image]

Comment: You're on to something there!